# Should I use Drush or Drupal Console with a new site?

Tags: 9

Between Drush and Drupal Console, which seems to have similar functionalities, which one should I install?

Comment: Drush, definitely. AFAIK Drupal Console is not compatible with Drupal 8.7-9, there are various issues in its issue queue, with the last commit being Nov 2019. https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues

Comment: One great thing about Drupal Console, that you can't do on drush command, is easily generating a custom module or a new block in a custom module. Here's a video on youtube, showing how easy it is to generate your own module: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXi6g1-pLXk

Comment: That's wrong. Drupal Console requires https://github.com/Chi-teck/drupal-code-generator as does Drush. Try [`drush generate controller`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/10.x/src/Commands/generate/GenerateCommands.php#L38) or try `drush generate theme --answers '{"Theme name": "test", "Theme machine name": "test", "Base theme": "Classy"}'` or try `drush generate block` etc. Have fun 

Comment: https://www.drush.org/commands/10.x/generate/

Comment: That may be, but does not negate the fact that you can no longer install Console on newer versions of Drupal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Drush.

Drush is about to be added to the `drupal/recommended-project`, see [#3159647](https://www.drupal.org/project/ideas/issues/3159647), while Drupal Console seems to be abandoned and currently is incompatible with Drupal 9 due to mismatched dependencies, see [#4251](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/4251).

Maybe Drupal Console finally accomplished its mission by triggering the modernisation of Drush. And there's no need for two CLIs. Now forces can be joined again.